# Java Arrays not working

Tags: java, arrays

**My Setup class:**

```
import static java.lang.System.*;

import java.util.Scanner;

import java.io.*;

public class Setup
{

private String[] roomtype, custAddress, custName;
private int[] cPhone;
private double[] roomPrice;
private int[] roomNumber;
Scanner kb = new Scanner(in);

    public Setup()
{

roomtype = new String[6];

custName = new String[6];

custAddress = new String[6];

roomPrice = new double[6];

cPhone = new int[6];

roomNumber = new int[6];

}

public void unoccupied()
{
    String answer;
    for (int c = 1; c<6; c++)
    {
        if(custName[c] == null)
        {
            out.println("Room" + roomtype[c] + " is not occupied.");
            out.print("Would you like to assign a customer to this room?");
                answer = kb.nextLine();
                if (answer.contains("y"))
                {
                    out.print("Which customer would you like to put in this room?");
                    answer = kb.nextLine();
                    roomtype[c] = answer;
                }
        }
    }
}
public void addName(String[] custName)
{
            for (int c = 1; c<6; c++)
        {
        if(custName[c] == null)
            {

            out.print("Add a name to customer " + c + ": ");
            custName[c] = kb.nextLine();

            }
        }
}
public void addcPhone(int[] cPhone)
{
    for (int p = 1; p<6; p++)
    {
        if(cPhone[p] == 0)
        {
        out.print("Add a cell phone number to customer " + p + ": ");
        cPhone[p] = kb.nextInt();
        }
    }

}
public void addAddress(String[] custAddress)
{
    for (int a = 1; a<6; a++)
        if(custAddress[a] == null)
        {
            if(custName[a] == null)
            {
            out.print("Add an address to customer " + a + ": ");
            custAddress[a] = kb.nextLine();
            }
            else
            out.print("Add an address to " + custName + ": ");
            custAddress[a] = kb.nextLine();
        }

}
public String toString()
{
    String receipt = "";
    receipt += "Customer Name: " + custName ;
    receipt += "Address: " + custAddress ;
    receipt += "Phone number: " + cPhone ;
    receipt += "Thanks for making your room reservation for Geek Speak with the Orozco Hotel!" ;
    receipt += "We have you booked in room number " + roomNumber + ", which is a " + roomtype + "." ;
    receipt += "Your charges for the convention will be $" + roomPrice + "." ;
    receipt += "We hope you enjoy your stay with us and the convention.";
    receipt += "The Orozco Hotel Staff";
    return receipt;
}
}
```

**And my driver class:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class Driver
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{


Scanner kb = new Scanner(in);
Setup[] customer = new Setup[5];
for(int i = 0; i<6; i++)
    customer[i] = new Setup(custName, cPhone, custAddress);

Setup[] room = new Setup[5];
for(int i = 0; i<6; i++)
    room[i] = new Setup(roomtype, roomPrice, roomNumber);
room[1].unoccupied();

}
}
```

Im trying to make 5 customer objects with custName, custAddress, and cPhone as parameters, and 5 room objects with roomPrice, roomtype, and roomNumber as parameters. I tried creating the objects with arrays, but I have no idea what I'm doing, as my teacher hasn't helped me at all this year. My driver class keeps returning the error "cannot find symbol" for the parameters in the customer and room objects. Any help to fix this code so that the objects hold the parameters is appreciated.

Comment: I'd start with having a single array and a class with all those fields in it.

Comment: First create single array pgrm.

Comment: you don't have a constructor for Setup class that can take parameters defined, then you try to construct a Setup object with params: `new Setup(custName, cPhone, custAddress);`

Comment: Where is the parameterised constructor in Setup class to take the argument as you are trying to do customer[i] = new Setup(custName, cPhone, custAddress);

Comment: Once you declare parameterized constructor change the for loop for(int i = 0; i<6; i++) to for(int i = 0; i<customer.length; i++) to avoid ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to reconsider your abstraction. These was a quick revamp to use a more OO approach. You can extend this idea by separating rooms from customer. You should have a hotel object be a collection of Rooms and customers.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Hotel{
LinkedList<Customer> customers;

public void addCustomer(Customer c){
    customers.add(c);
}
public void removeCustomer(int roomNumber){
    boolean flag = true;
    for(int i = 0; i < customers.size() && flag; ++i){
        if(customers.get(i).getRoomNumber() == roomNumber)
            customers.remove(i);
            flag = false;
    }
}

public String toString(){
    String s = "";
    for(Customer c : customers)
        s += c.toString() + "\n";
    return s;
}
}

class Customer {

private String roomType;
private String address;
private String name;
private String phone;
private String price;
private int roomNumber;

public Customer(String rmTp, String addrss, String nm, String phn, String prc, int rmNm){
    roomType   = rmTp;
    address    = addrss;
    name       = nm;
    phone      = phn;
    price      = prc;
    roomNumber = rmNm;
}

public int getRoomNumber(){ return roomNumber; }
public String toString(){
    String receipt = "";
    receipt += "Customer Name: " + name ;
    receipt += "Address: " + address ;
    receipt += "Phone number: " + phone ;
    receipt += "Thanks for making your room reservation for Geek Speak with the Orozco Hotel!" ;
    receipt += "We have you booked in room number " + roomNumber + ", which is a " + roomType + "." ;
    receipt += "Your charges for the convention will be $" + price + "." ;
    receipt += "We hope you enjoy your stay with us and the convention.";
    receipt += "The Orozco Hotel Staff";
    return receipt;
}

}
```